# possible to export FBX with texture paths?

Tags: texturing, export

I switch between Modo and Blender in my pipeline and exporting from Modo FBX to Blender is no problem. Exporting from Blender as FBX and importing back into Modo however loses all the texture assignments. The materials are all present but the association with any textures is lost. Is there a way to retain this information using FBX from Blender?

I don't want to embed the textures in the blend file as that will lead to duplicate textures. The textures sit in a repository separate from the Modo,Blend and FBX files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

cheers